# Изменить существующее поле в бд

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Не могу разобраться как изменить другие значения в поле при поиске определенного.

```
user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
telefon = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
confirmation = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
```

Есть данная модель, пользователь вводит номер

```
userAditional.objects.filter(telefon=phone_sim)
```

Проверяю на наличие в бд и если есть совпадение меняю **Confirmation на True**
Через сессии я реализовывал подобное, но если куки удалят, то все пропало.
Как можно получить остальные поля в бд зная только одно? Или только user_id вытянуть.

Answer (score 1):

```
userAditional.objects.filter(telefon=phone_sim).update(confirmation=True)
```

установит на все выбранные записи confirmation=True, вернёт количество обновлённых строк (int)